# Is RVM production ready?

Tags: ruby, rvm

RVM is great for developing on your local machine. But is it safe on a production machine?

Comment: If you haven't faced any bugs on your dev machine, I would assume its safe. [RVM is used for deployments too](http://beginrescueend.com/deployment/best-practices/).

Comment: RVM is plenty solid. A better question is, will it do what you want? Perhaps if you describe your goals we could make more useful suggestions. As is this is kind of nebulous.

Comment: The comment by the Tin Man is most excellent. The original question is to general to be answerable.

Comment: For those reading the responses: RVM in mid 2012 is a markedly different beast from RVM in mid 2011. I'm eating my words below and have started using RVM in our staging environment, with a view to moving it to our production environment.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

I built RVM for production and added the developer 'niceties' later on. 
If you would like more information read the documentation on the website and come talk to me in #rvm on irc.freenode.net sometime during the day EDT most days.

Comment: I'm curious, why would you consider it production ready when it overrides so many shell built-ins like 'cd'? If it were designed for production wouldn't you have confined rvm to your own wrapper or bash-like shell vs tainting the one that everybody/everything else depends on? You've effectively added ruby, tcl, etc into the mix of anything else that might have a !#/bin/bash at the top of it. Before RVM, all that was required was a functional libc6 install, just like the kernel. Every package policy I know of specifically prohibit what RVM is doing mostly in the name of production.

Comment: I'd have to agree here; rvm uses deeply ugly and unnecessary hooks into the shell when virtualenv solved the problem years before. Meanwhile, they break every few months and are prohibitive to debug. I recommend if you do use rvm, do not use any of the hooks it attempts to add without your consent.

Answer (score 22):

Since RVM is just a fancy way of downloading, isolating and switching between existing Ruby implementations, I'd say that it's as production ready as whatever ruby implementation you're currently running it with.

Essentially, all RVM does is point your path at a specific Ruby implementation. This is *exactly* what happens when you use your *nix distribution's Ruby implementation. The only real difference is that your path will be re-written so that when you run `ruby -v` it will run a ruby from your current user's .rvm directory instead of a global system directory like /usr/local/bin.

I'd go even further and say that using RVM is a better solution than using what generally gets installed in a *nix distro because it makes it easy to sandbox the specific ruby implementation on a per-user basis. RVM also makes it possible to attempt switching rubies (ie; from 1.8.7 to 1.9.2) on your production app while keeping a solid rollback strategy in place if something doesn't work quite right. It also makes it easier to keep old applications running on one version of Ruby, while switching new apps to more current versions.

Comment: Well thought out post, you summarized exactly what RVM does/is when used on production correctly. Environment files are the key to consistency there.

Comment: Thanks Wayne, it's good to know that I "get it". RVM is perhaps one of the most useful development tools I've ever used. I'm currently building an app that runs on JRuby, so RVM makes it easy to run my app on MRI in development (because MRI runs my tests much faster) and then switch to JRuby to test it out before I deploy. Kudos!

Answer (score 8):

I disagree, especially if you're using any kind of automated production process (puppet, chef, fog, etc) and you have more than one or two machines.

We've had issues where version X of RVM worked in a completely different way to version Y of RVM (different default Rubygems versions, different default gemset configs, complete changeup of how system wide install works), breaking our automated provisioning process.

Not an issue if you're developing and on hand to tune things, a killer if you have an unattended scripted / puppet install. We worked around these issues by locking to a particular RVM version, but I remember having a conversation with Wayne where he discouraged this. If we kept using RVM in prod, we were going to actually package it into a series of .debs (one for the install, one for each Ruby).

The way that .rvmrc prompts by default and can only be overriden in the homedir ~/.rvmrc (and not the system-wide one) was also unhelpful.

I actually like the way that RVM will change up and do things this way in development - nothing sucks more than being held back by backward compatibility.  This approach, however, cost us some time (and pulled hairs) in production/staging/uat/test.

Comment: For those reading this in 2012, things have changed and I'm now seriously considering RVM's use in production. From what I can tell, the releng has improved considerably.

Comment: .. but committing .rvmrc to your repo is still verboten.

Answer (score 6):

#### RVM is apparently a reasonable production tool

You know, I once made a similar *[rvm is a development tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670947/rvm-vs-native-installation-of-ruby)* comment and was informed that rvm was originally a production tool.

So, RVM will make your production environment more complex, which is bad, but it makes it more isolated and compartmentalized, what the language people would call *modular*, and that's good.

In the end, as long as you test your deployments, I don't see how a static configuration of any kind could be, all by itself, "unsafe".

Comment: I propose that it makes production environment *simpler* due to containment and specification :)

Comment: Heh, Wayne is the rvm author.  I can certainly believe that rvm simplifies the case where multiple environments are required.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on how you are installing RVM , single-user or multi-user . installing RVM system wide can cause lots of mess whole switching between different rubies. Better you opt for single user , minus that RVM does a good job for what it's meant to do .

Answer (score 3):

I guess there's two parts to this question:

1. Is RVM intended to be for production machines, as opposed to development machines?
2. Is RVM reliable enough software to be used on production machines?

For (1), Wayne E. Seguin has stated that it's intended to be used on production machines. There's no point in disputing his intent.

For (2), I'm not so sure. Is it appropriate to use software that has a new version number [every couple of days](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/commits/master/VERSION) on a production machine? Also, RVM once deleted my entire ~/ruby directory. To Wayne's credit, when I told him about it, he fixed it that night, but that doesn't exactly say "production ready" to me.

**Edit:** I've just [read about](https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee-Old-and-abbandoned/commit/a047be85247755cdbe0acce6f1dafc8beb84f2ac) bumblebee's deletion of /usr, and I'll just say - it could have been worse! LOL.

Comment: And how long ago was that? The project moves quickly and other than the installer recently things have no longer been changing much.
Additionally, what does having new version numbers frequently have to do with *anything*? Most of the time these are new features disjoint from what is already there.

Comment: If used CORRECTLY in 'production' there should be no issue.

Comment: Things have come a LONG way since then :)

Comment: @Wayne: Last December was still post 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using RVM on a production webserver for over a year now with zero problems.  I've kept it pretty up-to-date, running `rvm get head` frequently.  Zero issues, ever. :)

Comment: If it's supposed to be suitable for production, should you be constantly running `rvm get head`?

Comment: @Wayne: That kind of humor by itself makes it unsuitable for production! (I'm joking about it being a reason against using it, even though I roll my eyes every time I come across it).

Comment: There's much less of this "getting head" humor now than there used to be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've used rvm on production machines and also set up puppet modules to install rvm as the default system ruby along with gemsets, etc.

If you run multiple apps on a single server, rvm can help you keep all your apps gemsets (and ruby versions) totally separate. However, if you are running only a single app on a server, there may not be as much benefit to having rvm installed.

Comment: I disagree with the second part as that is the normal use case for most of the people I have worked with :)

Comment: RVM brings a little less awesome to a server running a single app than it does to a server running multiple apps. But in either case its awesomeness cannot be denied. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've pretty much used RVM on all my production servers running rails apps!. RVM has not let me down.